# Slide in and slideout using css3 and jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using css3 animation to slide down a div to a list having few set of divs. I am trying to achieve  a slide in and slide out effect like vertical news ticker in this site

http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/totem/index.html

Css

```
.slidein{ animation:slide 1799ms linear; top:0px; -webkit-animation:slide 1799ms linear;}

@keyframes slide
{
0%{ top:-100px;}
100%{ top:0px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes  slide
{
0%{ top:-100px;}
100%{ top:0px;}
}
```

Jquery

```
 $(".parentDiv").prepend('<div class="newdiv slidein"></div>').children().slice(5);
}
```

For Slide down i tried to use the follwing div to move it up and down using top and bottom values

```
$(".existingDivs").css({"bottom":""});
      $(".existingDivs").css({"bottom":"90px"});
     $(".existingDivs").animate({   
            top: '+=92'          
        },2000);
```

But it is not working in chrome and partially works in firefox.  Is there a way to append smooth sliding effect like  vertical ticker.

Comment: checked its working with chrome also.

Comment: @sonusindhu Its not giving a sliding effect.

Comment: hehehe same effect here with both chrome and mozilla

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `slide` from the CSS value. The browser will transition between the values you specify, which will be a slide anyway.

Why do you use jQuery to animate a different way? Why not use CSS3 transitions to then slide out?

Comment: It just "doesn't work" so you do nothing? Why don't you look into how CSS3 animations work, try fiddling around with your code and working out the solution? You might not even need help from people here.